# What is the correct parameter setting for smtp auth

Tags: php, authentication, smtp, sendmail

I have this script:

```
  // Define SMTP Parameters
  $params = array();
  $params['host']     = 'mail.mydomain.com';
  $params['port']     = '25';
  $params['auth']     = 'true';
  $params['username'] = 'valid@mydomain.com'; // this needs to be a legitimate mail account on the server and not an alias
  $params['password'] = 'abcdef';

  // Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
  include('Mail.php');
  $mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);
```

`params['auth']` does not seem to work when set to `'true'` but it does seem to work when set to `'PLAIN'`. Oddly, the doc only states `$params["auth"] - Whether or not to use SMTP authentication. Default is FALSE.` which makes it sound like you can use `FALSE` vs. `'PLAIN'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible authentication methods are:

- `'DIGEST-MD5'`
- `'CRAM-MD5'`
- `'LOGIN'`
- `'PLAIN'`

or `false` for no authentication.

http://pear.github.io/Net_SMTP/#smtp-authentication

PS: You could have noticed, that pear/Mail package is used. By the way it is relative old with latest changes in 2010

Comment: So how do you send mail on a LAMP sever through a PHP script using SMTP authentication @GennadiyLitvinyuk

Comment: I use Zend_Mail. @H.Ferrence

Comment: what does that look like? do you have a sample script @GennadiyLitvinyuk?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mail.transport.html @H.Ferrence